# AS3 How can I get back the object that being dragged to Item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I have board with 16 objects(MovieClip), every one of them have a unique instance name (slot1-16).
I'm trying to make a drag and drop code that return the instance name of the object dragged on it.

```
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    if(object is textBox || object is UILoader)
    {   
        for(var i:int = 1; i < 16; i++){
            //Checks the correct drop target
            if (object.hitTestObject(getChildByName("slot" + i))) 
            {
                trace("slot" + i);
                slot(getChildByName("slot" + i)).gotoAndStop(3);
            }else{
                object.x = xPos; //If not, return the clip to its original position
                object.y = yPos;
            }
        }

        object.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

What really happened is that the only place that i can drag in to is slot1, other slots are not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, if the 1st hit test with `slot1` object fails, you return your dragged object to its original position and of course all the hit tests with other slots will fail.

So you should return your object to its original position just after doing the hit test with all objects. You can use, for example, a Boolean var to know if there is at least one succeeded hit test, in that case you don't need to return your dragged object to its original position :

```
function fl_ReleaseToDrop(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    var hit_test:Boolean = false;

    if(object is textBox || object is UILoader)
    {   
        for(var i:int = 1; i < 16; i++)
        {           
            if (object.hitTestObject(getChildByName("slot" + i))) 
            {
                hit_test = true;
                slot(getChildByName("slot" + i)).gotoAndStop(3);
            }
        }
        if(!hit_test)
        {                   
            object.x = xPos;
            object.y = yPos;
        }           
        object.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: First of all, it work. But, not perfectly. Because all my target slots are on the stage in 4X4 sort, So i can't drop the item that i'm dragging exactly on the slot (he's sides touched other slots), then he change the frame of all the slots that he touched and not only the one i mean.

Comment: @Aviway So you should specify the slot that you mean and do the hit test just of it.

Comment: how can i specify the slot?

Comment: @Aviway I don't know the exact logic of your app, but you can associate a dragged object with a slot, and every time you do only the hit test between these two objects (e.g. `object_1` and `slot_1`, `object_2` and `slot_2`, ...).